# Replacing the same element in a list that is repeated

Tags: python, list

I'm attempting to replace an item in a list multiple times. The replaceable list already had all letters replaced with blanks, and I am using a reference list to find the proper locations, so I can replace elements of a list without destroying the main list.

For example

```
letters_in_word = list(apple)

for letter in letters_in_word:
    letter_location = letters_in_word.index(letter)
        for elements in replaceable_list:
            if guess is letter:
                replaceable_list[letter_location] = guess
```

However, whenever I guess all of the letters one after the other (making a game for school project) only the first of a duplicated letter is placed into the code.

Output:

```
_ p _ _ _
```

or

```
a p _ l e
```

How do I set the code to replace every duplicated item in a list, for any word?

Ideally, the result would be:

```
a p p l e
```

or

```
_ p p _ _
```

Comment: In this case you need to find the list of indexes for every guess. Like the following:   index_list = [i for i, a in enumerate(letters_in_word) if a == guess]   and then iterate through list to assign the values for all the index in the index_list

Comment: if user guessed 'p' do u want to replace blanks in this list `['_', '_', '_', '_', '_']`  to get --> `_ p p _ _`

Comment: Feel free to accept and upvote your favorite answer. This benefits both you and the answerer, and makes it easier for anyone who has a similar question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following using numpy comparisons:

```
import numpy as np

letters_in_word = np.array(list('apple'))

guess = 'p'
replaceable_list = np.zeros_like(letters_in_word)

for letter in letters_in_word:
    correct_guess = letters_in_word == guess
    replaceable_list[correct_guess] = guess


>> ['' 'p' 'p' '' '']
```

By way of explanation, `correct_guess` is a boolean array `[False, True, True, False, False]` pinpointing where the `guess` is equal to a letter in the word.
You can then use this boolean representation to assign all `True` locations a certain value in the output list.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a separate list to keep track of the correct answer. I haven't tested this, but something like:

```
hangman = ['_', '_', '_']
answer = ['p', 'i', 'e']
...
#when guessed, do the following
for x in hangman:
    for y in answer:
        if guess == answer[y]:
            hangman[y] = guess
```

Answer (score 0):

## Approach 1 ( recommended)

you can create a dictionary in which key will be letters of your answer like for `apple`, `dict keys` are `{a,p,l,e}` now all we need to do is loop over `list = ['a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e']` idx =
`'a( 0) p( 1) p(2) l ( 3) e( 4)'` and keep on appending index of letter as a value.

after doing this your dict will look like this `{'a': [0], 'p': [1, 2], 'l': [3], 'e': [4]})`

```
from collections import defaultdict

ans_list = list('apple')

replaceble_list = ['_']*len(ans_list)

guess = 'p'


char_idx_dict = defaultdict(list)

for idx,char in enumerate( ans_list):
    char_idx_dict[char].append(idx)

if guess in char_idx_dict:
    for idx in char_idx_dict[guess]:
        replaceble_list[idx] = guess

print(replaceble_list)

# ['_', 'p', 'p', '_', '_']
```

#### Approach 2 if you insist on using `list.index(x[, start[, end]])`

```
ans_list = list('apple')
replaceble_list = ['_']*len(ans_list)



def get_indices_list( user_letter):
    i = 0
    idx_list = []
    while i < len(ans_list):
        try:
            result = ans_list.index( user_letter, i, len(ans_list))
            idx_list.append( result)

        except ValueError:
            break

        i = result+1

    return idx_list

chance_left = 5

while chance_left  > 0:
    guess = input('enter ').lower()
    chance_left-=1

    if guess in ans_list:
        for idx in get_indices_list( guess):
            replaceble_list[idx] = guess

    print(replaceble_list)
    if replaceble_list == ans_list:
        print('you win')
        break

else:
    print('game over')
```

> ```
> '''
>
> enter a
> ['a', '_', '_', '_', '_']
> enter p
> ['a', 'p', 'p', '_', '_']
> enter l
> ['a', 'p', 'p', 'l', '_']
> enter e
> ['a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e']
> you win
>
> enter t
> ['_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
> enter u
> ['_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
> enter p
> ['_', 'p', 'p', '_', '_']
> enter o
> ['_', 'p', 'p', '_', '_']
> enter l
> ['_', 'p', 'p', 'l', '_']
> game over
>
> '''
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a helper function that takes in your hidden word, and your used letters.  The function would replace any "-" with the correct letter should it be guessed and subsequently return it.

```
def get_hidden_word(hidden_word, used_letters):
"""Returns a string of the form __ad___ by filling in correct guesses"""
visible_word = ""
for letter in hidden_word:
    if letter in used_letters:
        visible_word += letter
    else:
        if len(visible_word) > 0 and visible_word[-1] == '_':
            visible_word += " "
        visible_word += "_"
return visible_word
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a super simple solution I missed:

```
for letter in range(len(letters_in_word)):
    if letters_in_word[letter] == guess:
        replaceable_list[letter] = guess
    joined_letters = " ".join(replaceable_list)
```

I didn't realize I could have set up this simple range parameter to use in place of all the for statements. The more you know!

Thanks for the suggestions everyone, but unfortunately I just started learning Python 2 weeks ago, and barely understand half the suggestions posted. Thanks for the attempt though, I appreciate it.